# EF Core Diagnostics - Query count per context instance

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to instrument EF by inspecting how many queries are made per context instance. We generally don't expect more than 10 or so queries on a context, so I want to use this to check if a context has been misused such as making query calls inside a loop, which leads to obvious performance issues.

I basically want to say if the number of queries against any given context > X, then log an error or even throw an exception.

The closest thing I can find is using is using [Diagnostic Listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/diagnostic-listeners) for the event id: RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted.Name, however there is no reference to the context in the event data to be able to track this on a per context basis. Event Counters are not really a viable solution either because they are global counters.

Does anyone know if what I would like to do is possible in any other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, it turns out from EF Core 3+ the Context instance was added to CommandCorrelatedEventData in DbCommandInterceptor, along with a ContextId on DbContext, which gives you everything you need to track query counts.

Here is an interceptor example that limits the number of commands run per context instance:

```
public class QueryInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    // TODO: Use an expiring cache
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<DbContextId, int> _queryCountsPerContext = new();

    public override InterceptionResult<DbCommand> CommandCreating(CommandCorrelatedEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbCommand> result)
    {
        OnQueryExecuted(eventData);
        
        return base.CommandCreating(eventData, result);
    }

    private void OnQueryExecuted(CommandCorrelatedEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.Context == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        if (!_queryCountsPerContext.TryGetValue(eventData.Context.ContextId, out var count))
        {
            count = 0;
        }

        count++;
        
        _queryCountsPerContext[eventData.Context.ContextId] = count;

        if (count > Constants.QueryLimitPerContextInstance)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Too many queries for context instance! Limit: {Constants.QueryLimitPerContextInstance}");
        }
    }
}
```

Gist with full example: https://gist.github.com/cjbhaines/acdb69a47520e8b4b43b03a754150bc6